# Add to cart function with product ID's

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, e-commerce, opencart

Ive built a custom product builder for my site, and am stuck at the very last step - adding the products to the cart.

so on my custom template file I have this code firing when the 'Add to Cart' button is clicked:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('I WANT TO PUT PRODUCT ID HERE, BUT DOESNT WORK'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {

    }
});
```

I have the product id saved as a javascript variable, I just need to actually get it to add this product to the cart. Any help would be great. Thanks.

**_____________** EDIT **______________**

This is my most recent code, the function is definitely being fired when I click the add to cart button, locketID is simply a product id. The success function is being called but neither of the if statements (error or success) and being executed, and the product isn't being added to to the cart.

Is it worth mentioning that this is happening on the category template file? Is there anything that needs included that might not be?

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: locketID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            console.log('success function called')

            if (json['error']) {
                console.log('ERROR');
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
            }


        }
    });
});
```

**___________EDIT__________**

So, I've taken a slightly different approach this is what I have in the being called on the add to cart button click, but it redirects to the product page rather than add the product to the cart, any ideas?

```
$('#button-cart-custom').bind('click', function() {

    var quantity = 1;
    var product_id = 12196;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Can you specify the part where you say "BUT DOESNT WORK"?

Comment: I want to put the id of the products I want added to the cart here

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

```
var vars = new Array();

vars = {var1: var1_value,var2: var2_value}
```

now replace in your code

`data: $('I WANT TO PUT PRODUCT ID HERE, BUT DOESNT WORK'),` with `data: vars;`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I thought something like that would work, but I'm not getting anywhere with it. I've updated the question above with my latest code, and explanation. Thanks again

Comment: replace data: locketID with  data:{'id':locketID}  and use $_POST['id'] to get that data

Comment: sorry, where am I putting $_POST['id']

Comment: its to use on  index.php page  so that you could get that ID

Comment: I'm appreciating your help...just can't see where to add $_POST['id']

Comment: dear friend $_POST['id'] has nothing to with your jquery code you will use it in your php script(where you make a cart update request) to know that which id has been sent

Comment: I know it's a little bit late but ,you put the $_POST['id']  in the target file , in your case that's index.php and since you're using post method you don't need to append the "?route=checkout/cart/add" to your index.php in the URL 

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

replace `data: locketID` 
with

```
data:{'id':locketID}
```

and 
use

`$_POST['id']` to get that data on server

Comment: also remove dataType: 'json', form your code no need of it